# ThreeJS scene runs at 60FPS, but turns my fans up and eventually crashes

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm new to threeJS, so I decided to experiment with this example:
http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_fps

I exported some terrain that I made in blender and replaced the platform.json file. The scene was running at 55-60fps, I had no real issues with lag, but it'd gradually cause my fans to ramp up louder and louder. Eventually the page would just stop responding. Which is surprising because my computer specs are pretty good.

According to rendererstats.js my scene has 23k vertices and 7k faces. I thought maybe this was the issue, but it persisted despite cutting the count in half. I Googled around and experimented without much success. I then tried the original demo (linked above) and realized that my computer reacted the same way.

What is it about this demo that you think could be causing the problem and is there a fix? I really appreciate any help figuring this out.

Comment: Demo is fine for me. It may be problems with your computer.

Comment: 23k vertices and 7k faces is not performance issue even on a average laptop.

Comment: Check out your garbage collector and actions during loop like for/foreach ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo seems to be fine. I don't know where the problem is but I might say some facts.

Browser itself doesn't need graphic card to run, but once you open tab with webgl, it might request hardware to use it. This also might result in turning fans regardless of the WebGL app requirements. It is really hardware/firmware thingy. 
I had similar problem before and it turns out my laptop was broken.

So first I suggest try to eliminate your problem, do GPU benchmark or test antoher app (games) if your device has similar problems or not.
If it doesn't then try to eliminate the problem with webgl. Try different browser with this demo. Also try more webgl apps and try to find out if there is problem with three.js apps only, or any webgl app or only this app.

- If there is a problem with every app in any browser, problem will be very deep and I can't help much since I don't know your configuration.
- If the problem is with this demo with any browser, but other apps are good, I guess problem might be somewhere between WebGL and your graphic card (some specific WebGL/GLSL function) so it is also very deep. It might be reported to webgl developers community where are also graphic cards vendors.
- If the problem is only with one browser, it might be the browser setup or browser itself. You might try to reinstall it or report it to browser developers.
- If the problem is in one browser and only this demo, it is the browser and Threejs related problem. And you can only do deeper demo benchmarking and try to report it to Threejs developers.

Sorry this might not be an answer, but it was too long for comment.